# How to show the following weak convergence using characteristic functions

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, statistics, weak-convergence, characteristic-functions

Suppose $g:R\rightarrow R$ has at least three bounded continuous derivatives and let $X_i$ be $iid$ and in $L^2$. Prove that:

$\sqrt{n}[g(\overline{X_n}) - g(\mu)]\xrightarrow{w} N(0,g^{'}(\mu)^{2} \sigma ^2)$  i.e. weak convergence happens

where $\overline{X_n} = \frac{\sum X_n}{n}$, $\mu = EX_1$, $\sigma^2=Var(X_1)$

My attempt:
Let $\phi$ be the characteristic function/fourier transform. Weak convergence $\iff$ convergence of $\phi$
On the RHS, $N(0,g^{'}(\mu)^{2} \sigma ^2) \sim  g^{'}(\mu) \sigma N(0,1) = g^{'}(\mu) \sigma \mathscr{X}$  where $\mathscr{X}$ is standard normal

$\phi_{g^{'}(\mu) \sigma  \mathscr{X}}(t) = \phi_{\mathscr{X}}(g^{'}(\mu) \sigma t) = e^{-\frac{g^{'}(\mu)^{2} \sigma ^2 t^2}{2}}$ because $\phi_{\mathscr{X}}(t) = e^{-\frac{t^2}{2}}$

On the LHS:
The characteristic function is

$E[e^{it\sqrt{n}g(\overline{X_n}) - it\sqrt{n}g(\mu)}] = e^{-it\sqrt{n}g(\mu)} E[e^{it\sqrt{n}g(\overline{X_n})}]$
Because RHS has $g^{'}(\mu)$, I am thinking of expanding $e^{it\sqrt{n}g(\overline{X_n})}$ using Taylor's which is:
$e^{it\sqrt{n}g(\overline{X_n})} \approx e^{it\sqrt{n}g(\mu)} + e^{it\sqrt{n}g(\mu)}it\sqrt{n}g'(\mu)(\overline{X_n}-\mu)+e^{it\sqrt{n}g(\mu)}it\sqrt{n}g'(\mu)[(it\sqrt{n}g'(\mu))^2 + it\sqrt{n}g^{''}(\mu)](\overline{X_n}-\mu)^2$

So $LHS = e^{-it\sqrt{n}g(\mu)} E[e^{it\sqrt{n}g(\overline{X_n})}] = 1+[(it\sqrt{n}g'(\mu))^2 + it\sqrt{n}g^{''}(\mu)]E[\overline{X_n}-\mu]^{2} =$
$1+[(it\sqrt{n}g'(\mu))^2 + it\sqrt{n}g^{''}(\mu)](\frac{\sigma^2}{n}+\mu^2)$

I am stuck at this point as $RHS$ has $e$ to the some power which means $LHS$ needs to have a $(1+x/n)^n$ kind of a situation which I don't. Basically, I am missing a power $n$ on the $LHS$ which should occur because of $\overline{X_n}$ but $g(\overline{X_n})$ kind of blocks that to happen. A hint is appreciated about the whole approach, thanks.

Comment: It's like $e^{u-v} = e^{-v}e^{u}$ and can take $e^{-v}$ out of the expectation as it is a constant. If $Y := \sqrt{n}(g(\bar{X_n})-g(\mu))$, I am just doing $\phi_Y(t)=E\{e^{itY}\}$

Comment: Ah sorry, I misread what you wrote, sorry.

Comment: No worries, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the strong law of large numbers, we have $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{g(\overline{X_n}) - g(\mu)}{\overline{X_n}-\mu} = g'(\mu)$$
almost surely. By the central limit theorem and Slutsky's theorem, it follows that
$$\sqrt{n}[g(\overline{X_n}) - g(\mu)] = \frac{g(\overline{X_n}) - g(\mu)}{\overline{X_n}-\mu}\cdot \sqrt{n} (\overline{X_n} - \mu) \xrightarrow{w} g'(\mu)X, $$
where $X \sim N(0,\sigma^2).$

Comment: Thanks, you are right, that was my solution too but am wondering if it can be proved using characteristic functions, a bit tedious, for sure.